# ldap search filter with java

Tags: java, string, search, filter, ldap

I'm having problems with ldap search filters.
I want to search through all the children of a root node. I want the users where the username of the email contains the query string.
for example, if I have

- foo_l.c_bar@foobar.com
- foobar@foo_l.c_bar

and the search query is "l.c" I want only foo_l.c_bar@foobar.com

the following code, surprisingly, returns either the first and the second.

```
String query = "...";
DirContext dc = ...;
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> ne = dc.search(root,
    "(email=*{0}*@*)",
    new Object[] { query }, null);
```

what's wrong in the `"*...*@*"` query filter?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a full answer, but if you try a `ldapsearch` from command line with the filter `"(email=*l.c*@*)"`, you should get the right records ... so I would say the problem is in the Java method and not in the filter.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: unfortunately ATM I don't have a linux machine w/ ldapsearch installed.
The only ldap manager I have is JXplorer which return all the records, not only the right ones.
AFAIK it is written in java itself, so I don't know if it's me or java.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I assume you forgot to paste the code that formatted your query and its {0} parameter ?</strike>
edit:  wow, forget me, I didn't even know about the method that takes the filterArgs array.

As a side note, the standard attribute for e-mail address in inetOrgPerson is "mail" not "email" (but it might be different on your case of course)